# How can I augment the margin of an element from the Dom in my script?

Tags: javascript, dom, switch-statement

I'm trying to move the button through the body using arrows.
It's wrong to put numeric literals, and I tested that the code it's linked to the HTML.

```
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (evt) {
    
    const btn = document.querySelector('button');
    switch(evt.code) {
        
        case 'ArrowUp':
            btn.style.marginBottom =+ 10;
        break;

        case 'ArrowDown':
            btn.style.marginTop =+ 10;
        break;

        case 'ArrowRight':
            btn.style.marginLeft += 10;
        break;

        case 'ArrowLeft':
            btn.style.marginRight =+ 10;
        break;

        default:

    }
})
```

Comment: IMO it's a mistake to the the DOM as a store of state (which is effectively the case when you try to `+=` on the values from the DOM). Why not introduce variables in your code to track the intended margin values, then just write them to the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

marginLeft and other return a string (with "px" text), so you have to remove it in order to make sum.

```js
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (evt) {
    
    const btn = document.querySelector('#mybutton');
 
    switch(evt.code) {
        
        case 'ArrowUp':
            btn.style.marginTop = (parseInt(btn.style.marginTop.replace("px","")) - 10) + "px";
        break;

        case 'ArrowDown':
        btn.style.marginTop = (parseInt(btn.style.marginTop.replace("px","")) + 10) + "px";
        break;

        case 'ArrowRight':
        btn.style.marginLeft = (parseInt(btn.style.marginLeft.replace("px","")) + 10) + "px";
        break;

        case 'ArrowLeft':
                btn.style.marginLeft = (parseInt(btn.style.marginLeft.replace("px","")) - 10) + "px";

        break;

        default:

    }
})
```

```html
<div>before</div>
    <button id="mybutton" style="margin:1px">hello</button>
    <div>after</div>
```